# Скрытие блока кода в sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

Добрый день, уважаемые!
Куда-то пропали треугольнички на вертикальной линейке слева окна редактора sublime text 3, при нажатии на которые можно было скрывать блок кода (скрин прилагаю). Нигде не нашел, как их восстановить. Может быть кто-то подскажет, как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

В настройках поставить: 
`"fold_buttons": true` -и все.